# All I want to do is talk (infinitive +simple verb)

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

So there's this weird grammar structure I came across in a series, As far as grammar is concerned the following statement

> All I want to/wanna do is talk

Whereas in the standard English it should be either of these

> All I want to/wanna do is to talk
>
> All I want to/wanna do is talking

Thus I was wondering what grammar structure precisely it follows. Some other friend of mine said to me "**talk** here's a noun" where I was like "so is **talking** in my example, therefore it has to be something else involved in".

*Could anyone explain what grammar it follows here?*

Comment: "Wanna" is never used in Standard English

Comment: @BillJ I know right. that's not the matter here though.

Comment: "Talk" (or "to talk") is a verb; it heads the non-finite infinitival clause functioning as predicative complement of "be". Note that it could take adverbial modification, as in "All I want to do is talk sensibly", or a PP complement as in "All I want to do is talk to Ed". "Talking" would be ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ Could you just speak English? :/ I didn't get a word

Comment: "Talk" (or "to talk") is not a noun; it's a verb. I gave you the grammatical structure that you asked for.

Comment: @BillJ that's it I knew it's a verb here, that was what my friend said "it's a noun". and what's with the "to" here that's omitted?

Comment: "Talk" is one of a few verbs that can be used as bare infinitival (without the _to_) or as a _to_ infinitival. Both are correct here; it's a free choice.

Comment: @BillJ I dont think *to talk* is acceptable. If you say *talk* can be used as to-infinitival. Try subtitute it with other verbs.

Comment: @user178049 When the clause is predicative complement, "to" can be added: "the only thing I want to do is (to) talk/eat/sleep" and so on. Cf. also: "All I wanted to do was (to) print out the report".

Answer (score 3):

When the clause is predicative complement and the subject NP contains "do" in a relative clause, the usual form is a bare infinitival, but "to" can optionally be added:

*All I did was (to) print out the table of contents*.

Answer (score 0):

Because the complement of "want" is "to do", the complement of "is" must be an expression of *action or activity*.  If it had been "All I want to *drink* is..." the complement of "is" would have to be a beverage of some kind, anything that can be drunk.

**All I want to do is {action}.

All I want to drink is {beverage}.**

An infinitive, either marked by "to" or unmarked, can be an expression of action or activity:

> All I want|hope|plan|intend|wish
>
> to do
>
> is
>
> work|play|run|walk|sing|sit in silence|eat|fast|vegetate|pray|curse...
>
> to prognosticate|to watch TV|to drink beer|to play poker|to burp...

The action or activity can even be expressed with the verb "have" or "be", as long as semantically the phrase is understood to express action or activity or refraining from action or activity:

> have sex|be chaste...

Comment: So that means the expression of action/activity can be infinitive or to-infinitive?

Comment: Yes, bare infinitive (sing) or the marked infinitive (to sing).

Comment: There is something confusing me when it's past tense, like "All I did was", why use *was* after *did*? Why not *is*?

Comment: You will hear native speakers say both: "All I did *was* give it a little shove" or "All I did *is* give it a little shove".  The reference is to a past action, so "was" makes sense, no?  But if the nature of the action is more important to the speaker than the time of the action, or is the only important thing, the speaker might subconsciously choose the present tense "is".  Native speakers are not all equally scrupulous in their choice of tense.